# rpy2 - unable to install R packages

Tags: python, r, jupyter, rpy2

Here is my piece of code and i am installing R library RPostgreSQL in python

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
import rpy2.robjects.packages as rpackages
utils = rpackages.importr('utils')
utils.install_packages('RPostgreSQL')
```

but it gives errors :

```
RRuntimeError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-04e0baa1a451> in <module>()
----> 1 utils.install_packages('RPostgreSQL')

c:\users\postgres\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site- 
packages\rpy2\robjects\functions.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
176                 v = kwargs.pop(k)
177                 kwargs[r_k] = v
--> 178         return super(SignatureTranslatedFunction, 
self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
179 
180 pattern_link = re.compile(r'\\link\{(.+?)\}')

c:\users\postgres\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site- 
packages\rpy2\robjects\functions.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
104         for k, v in kwargs.items():
105             new_kwargs[k] = conversion.py2ri(v)
--> 106         res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, 
**new_kwargs)
107         res = conversion.ri2ro(res)
108         return res

RRuntimeError: Error in (function (pkgs, lib, repos = getOption("repos"), 
contriburl = contrib.url(repos,  : 
unable to install packages
```

I have tried many suggestions, and this is my .libpaths and library postgresql is installed in both. Any help ?

## RStudio

```
"C:/Users/postgres/R/win-library/3.5"
"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.0/library"
```

Comment: Why don't you just install from inside R, and once that is done, call from Python?  Adding the extra Python layer _for the installation_ is likely going to obstruct error messages etc.

Comment: the library is already installed in R and i have coded in R too but now i want to call that in Python. Is there any other way ?

Comment: Did you maybe confuse the `library(RPostgreSQL)` call with `install.packages()`?  I can't tell.

Comment: May be, but i have done both, Thanks for the response